# Find device by browser

Tags: device

Using formstack they record the browser with each form submission.  From this I would like to reveal the device, be it desktop, tablet or mobile.  Is there a database that will decode this?  I have 317 different browsers like the following:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; MAARJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 

Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36

Chrome 47.0.2526.106 / Windows

IE 10.0 / Windows 8

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 

Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.47
```

Answer (score 0):

[UserAgentString.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/All/) has a **list of user agent strings** that seems rather comprehensive and also offers a [RESTful API](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/api.php).
This should help you decode the strings automatically.

---

If you are working with **JavaScript**, also [have a look at UAParser.js](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js):

```
var result = UAParser('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.10 Chromium/15.0.874.106 Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2');

console.log(result.browser);          // {name: "Chromium", version: "15.0.874.106"}
console.log(result.device);           // {model: undefined, type: undefined, vendor: undefined}
console.log(result.os);               // {name: "Ubuntu", version: "11.10"}
console.log(result.os.version);       // "11.10"
console.log(result.engine.name);      // "WebKit"
console.log(result.cpu.architecture); // "amd64"
```

For **PHP**, [the function `get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) can help you with that:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>

---------------------

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7) Gecko/20040803 Firefox/0.9.3

Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0\.9.*$
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*
    [parent] => Firefox 0.9
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 0.9
    ....
}
```